# Auto sync Windows 10 Mail app

Tags: windows-10, email, imap, windows-10-mail-app

I have a problem with Mail app on a Windows 10 system (updated from Windows 8).
The sync settings just don't work on any email accounts and (of course) in the calendar app. I can open mail app up and force a manual refresh/sync which will also update the calendar with entries I make remotely or via phone but the regularity of checks is not working. Do others see this? It kind of makes the lives tiles redundant as the actual apps will only sync manually.
I've checked other solutions like

- Enable\Disable sync options in Settings under "Calendar" section
- Run troubleshooting app from Microsoft
- Rebooting system
- Set app sync on "as items arrive" or "every 15 minutes"
- Update mail app
- Disable firewall

None of these "fixes" worked. Everything else is working fine. If I press sync button it works (it downloads mail and calendar events) but the app doesn't do this automatically.
(IMAP account)

Someone has\had same problem? And have you managed to rectify this problem?